# UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: ACCESS_VIOLATION (C0000005)

Tags: diablo-ii

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: ACCESS_VIOLATION (C0000005)
```

This error can signify a variety of issues but what does it mean in the context of Diablo II, and what is the workaround?

(Also sometimes shows as an empty white box with a red X icon...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is most likely with graphics card compatibility in newer Windows.

The easiest solution is to use [Sven's GLIDE wrapper](http://www.svenswrapper.de/english/):

1. [Download](http://www.svenswrapper.de/english/downloads.html) the version that corresponds with your Diablo II release.
2. Run the exe and move the resulting `.ini` file and the folder's `.dll` to your Diablo II folder
3. Run `d2vidtst.exe` in your Diablo II folder and pick GLIDE (the third option) when it finishes
4. Voilà

Comment: Be aware that a "recent" D2 patch has removed the d2vidtst.exe if it hasn't been fixed yet. (Because you know, what else does Blizzard have to do except ruin the only fix to a 15 year old game?).
I think there was some other way to install the glide wrapper correctly, but it might require some research.